# MongoEngine slicing queryset (mongodb with django)

Tags: django, mongodb, mongoengine

I have a queryset like this in python.

```
notes = Note.objects[:10]
```

if i do len(notes) it gives me 10 which is correct. But when i pass "notes" object to template and try

```
{{notes|length}}
```

then i get 16 (which is total count of note data). Even if i do `Note.objects.limit(5)` it's the same. Is this a bug in MongoEngine? or am i doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a bug in MongoEngine.
Issue about this can be found on;
https://github.com/hmarr/mongoengine/issues/166